# I have two df and large in size, and I can not join them in my system, then what will be my approach towared that?

Tags: apache-spark

I have two df and large in size, and I can not join them in my system, then what will be my approach towared that

Comment: `I can not join them in my system` - what does that suppose to mean? Are you getting any exceptions? Please add more details to the question.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.